# Reasons for questions of this type to be downvoted and closed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

My [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96485/is-angry-bird-becoming-easier-with-new-versions) regarding the possibility that "Angry Birds" is becoming easier with new versions was closed after being down-voted 8 times. (After an encouraging single up-vote.)

I tried to present the question itself and the motivation behind it as clearly as I could. On the face of it, the question seems on-topic and it is close to an earlier [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44595/is-angry-birds-deterministic) that was very well accepted, if "Angry Birds" involves randomness. The randomness question attracted also good and definite answers. I expect that similar good and definite answers to my question are possible as well.

**Update:** I accepted MBraedly's answer. While I disagree that the question is inherently speculative and that the only way to get a definite insight is to ask the Devs, I appreciate this point of view.

Comment: The only way anybody would know a definite answer to this question would be if you worked for Rovio. It promotes discussion and speculation which makes it a bad fit for our Q&A format.

Comment: While I appreciate the obvious amount of effort you put in the  question, I just don't think this kind of meta-game questions where we compare and contrast different games is something on topic for us. I do not feel strongly either way, so I'm only posting a comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question was closed as not constructive because

> this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

All of those are true for your question.  Additionally, your question is a bit of an "Ask the Devs" question, which while not in the FAQ, has been agreed upon by the community to be off topic because they are inherently speculative.  The down-votes were cast for these very same reasons.

It's not because you didn't put a lot of work into your question (you obviously did), but because your question just isn't a good fit for our Q&A model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I disagree that the question is inherently speculative and that the only way to get a definite insight is to ask the Devs, but I appreciate this point of view.